# Spring Boot: Accessing Thymeleaf Model Attributes in Javascript getting the Error

Tags: java, spring

Getting this Error...while using inline JavaScript in Thymeleaf.
This Error is showing in my console..

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]

2020-04-06 12:47:31.262 ERROR 6764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/filter] and exception [An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/employeesFiltered.html]")] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.

```
<nav th:replace="layouts :: navbar"></nav>

<div class="container">
    <h3>Employee Directory</h3>
    <hr>

    <!--  Add New Employees Button -->
    <a th:href="@{/employees/new}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">
        Add Employee </a> <input id="txt-search" type="text" class="form-control"
        name="keyword" placeholder="Search...">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="aEmployee : ${employees}">
                <td th:text="${aEmployee.firstName}" />
                <td th:text="${aEmployee.lastName}" />
                <td th:text="${aEmployee.email}" />
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>

<!-- According to the official documentation: -->

<script th:inline="javascript"> 
/*<![CDATA[*/
var user = /*[[${employees}]]*/;
alert(user);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: How does the Employee Java class look like? Is it a bean with getters?

Comment: Hi RoToTa, Yes it's an @Entity with setter & getters.